# My graph is not show plotting

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot some of function below.
I could plot two of functions f[x_] & g[x_] but fail h[x_]
How to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Clearly you need specific values for all these parameters you have there. `alpha, Ms, Hext, a, offset, Itot` etc..  for any hope of getting a plot. Also, better to post plain text code. It is hard to copy code from an image. And you should really be using `:=` instead of `=` for function definitions as a general rule.  If you had these defined but did not show them, then the other thing that could be is that you are getting complex values from `h[x]` so you should check it at some value before plotting it.

Comment: Look carefully at what this shows `alpha=1;ms=2;CapNext=3;Itot=4;w=5;a=6;offset=7;
f[x_]:=-(alpha/(ms+CapNext))*(Itot/(2*3.14*w))*Log[(x-a)/(w-x+a)]+offset;
g[x_]:=(1/(2*Pi*(0.9)^2))Exp[-(x^2/(0.9)^2)];
h[y_]:=(Print[{{g[x],f[x],x,y},q=Convolve[g[x],f[x], x,y]}];q);
Plot[h[x],{x,-5,45}]` to see that `Convolve` is not given what it needs.

Comment: Perhaps try `h[y_]:=Convolve[g[u],f[v],u,v]/.v->y; Plot[ReIm[h[x]],{x,-5,45},PlotRange->{-.25,2.25}]` Perhaps add Print and study that carefully to see if the `Convolve` is now exactly correct. If you use `h[y_]:=Convolve[g[u],f[v],u,v]/.v->y; Plot[h[x],{x,-5,45}]` it only shows a real part of the plot. Perhaps include `PlotPoints->100` or more to see more detail.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful